# How to create a new dataframe from an existing one grouping by day and individual and calculating proportions?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe with info about the state (`State`) of different individuals (`ID`) over time (`Datetime`). Below I show an example of what I have:

```
  df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(c("A"),8),rep(c("B"),8)),
                   Datetime=c("2020-08-05 12:00:00","2020-08-05 17:00:00","2020-08-05 18:03:00","2020-08-05 22:54:00","2020-08-06 01:08:00","2020-08-06 13:26:00","2020-08-06 19:04:00","2020-08-08 11:00:00",
                              "2020-08-04 03:00:00","2020-08-04 15:00:00","2020-08-04 23:00:00","2020-08-06 14:00:00","2020-08-06 17:00:00","2020-08-06 20:00:00","2020-08-07 04:00:00","2020-08-07 16:00:00"),
                   State=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1))

  df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

  
  df

   ID            Datetime State
1   A 2020-08-05 12:00:00     1
2   A 2020-08-05 17:00:00     2
3   A 2020-08-05 18:03:00     1
4   A 2020-08-05 22:54:00     1
5   A 2020-08-06 01:08:00     1
6   A 2020-08-06 13:26:00     1
7   A 2020-08-06 19:04:00     2
8   A 2020-08-08 11:00:00     2
9   B 2020-08-04 03:00:00     1
10  B 2020-08-04 15:00:00     1
11  B 2020-08-04 23:00:00     1
12  B 2020-08-06 14:00:00     2
13  B 2020-08-06 17:00:00     2
14  B 2020-08-06 20:00:00     1
15  B 2020-08-07 04:00:00     1
16  B 2020-08-07 16:00:00     1
```

I want to calculate the proportion of time by day that each one of my individuals has spent in state `1` and `2`. That is, I would like to get this:

```
  ID   DateTime State.1 State.2
1  A 2020-08-05    0.75    0.25  # Individual `A` was in 3 out of the four records (=rows) in state `1` for this day.
2  A 2020-08-06    0.66    0.33
3  A 2020-08-08    0.00    1.00
4  B 2020-08-04    1.00    0.00
5  B 2020-08-06    0.33    0.66
6  B 2020-08-07    1.00    0.00
```

However, I don't know how exactly proceed to do all this at once, and my dataframe is too large to do it manually.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(date = format(Datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d')) %>% group_by(ID, date) %>% 
summarise(State.1 = sum(+(State == 1))/n(), State.2 = sum(+(State == 2))/n())

`summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
  ID    date       State.1 State.2
  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A     2020-08-05   0.75    0.25 
2 A     2020-08-06   0.667   0.333
3 A     2020-08-08   0       1    
4 B     2020-08-04   1       0    
5 B     2020-08-06   0.333   0.667
6 B     2020-08-07   1       0
```

Updated answer to include missing dates:

```
df %>% mutate(date = format(Datetime, format = '%Y-%m-%d')) %>% group_by(ID, date) %>% 
summarise(State.1 = sum(+(State == 1))/n(), State.2 = sum(+(State == 2))/n()) %>% 
ungroup() %>%  complete(ID, nesting(date))
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 10 x 4
   ID    date       State.1 State.2
   <chr> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 A     2020-08-04  NA      NA    
 2 A     2020-08-05   0.75    0.25 
 3 A     2020-08-06   0.667   0.333
 4 A     2020-08-07  NA      NA    
 5 A     2020-08-08   0       1    
 6 B     2020-08-04   1       0    
 7 B     2020-08-05  NA      NA    
 8 B     2020-08-06   0.333   0.667
 9 B     2020-08-07   1       0    
10 B     2020-08-08  NA      NA    
>
```

Comment: Thanks @Karthik S. It works perfectly. Could I ask you something? Would it be possible to include dates for which there is no data within the range of my first and last date? That is, for instance, for `A`, is there a way to get that the date `2020-08-07` appears in the dataframe? It should appear `NA` in this case, but it would be handy to have those dates also in the dataframe for illustrative purposes.

Comment: @Dekike, have updated my answer, please check if it works for you.

Comment: One extra doubt @Karthik S. Before, I apologize for disturbing you. I have realized that I forgot to include an extra variable before calculating proportions. I have a variable called `Time_of_day` that has the levels "Day" and "Night". Thus, I would like to consider the % of the time by date in state `1` and `2`, but also considering the `Time of day`, so I would have `State.1_day`, `State.1_night`, `State.2_day`, `State.2_night`. I am going to try it from your code, If I can't get it, I will let you know in case you can help me... Thanks again for your time.

Comment: What I have done is to change the last part, after `%>%summarise(...`. I change it by `summarise(State.1_day = sum(+(State == 1 & Period=="Day"))/n(), State.1_night = sum(+(State == 1 & Period=="Night"))/n(), State.2_day = sum(+(State == 2 & Period=="Day"))/n(), State.2_night = sum(+(State == 2 & Period=="Night"))/n())`. Do you think it is correct? I am observing the results and they seem to be right.

Comment: @Dekike, looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work, just want to use functions I recently learned:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(dt = substring(Datetime, 1, 10), val = 1) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = c(ID, dt),
    names_from = State,
    values_from = val,
    names_glue = "State.{State}",
    values_fn = sum,
    values_fill = 0
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    State.1 = State.1/(State.1 + State.2),
    State.2 = 1 - State.1
  )

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  ID    dt         State.1 State.2
  <chr> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A     2020-08-05   0.75    0.25 
2 A     2020-08-06   0.667   0.333
3 A     2020-08-08   0       1    
4 B     2020-08-04   1       0    
5 B     2020-08-06   0.333   0.667
6 B     2020-08-07   1       0    
>
```

Comment: It does not provide the results I would expect, but thanks for your time @roy.

Comment: Thank you for helping me fix the error, but I am wondering if there is a better way? such as `values_fn = count` in pivot_wider(), but obviously this will fail@AnilGoyal